# how to do arithmetic on objects

Tags: java, math

I have a few `BigInteger` objects in a two simple java files. But, since they aren't primitive types, the arithmetic operators won't work on them.

There is an error every time an operator is used, like so:

```
.\_Mathematics\Formulas\Factorial.java:10: error: bad operand types for binary o
perator '*'
                        result *= i;
                               ^
  first type:  BigInteger
  second type: int
```

Here they are:

```
package _Mathematics.Formulas;
import java.math.*;

public class Factorial<T extends Number> {
    public T o;
    public BigInteger r;
    public Factorial(int num) {
        BigInteger result = new BigInteger("1");
        for(int i = num; i > 0; i--)
            result *= i;
        this.o = num;
        this.r = result;
    }
}
```

and

```
package _Mathematics.Formulas;
import java.math.*;

public class Power<T extends Number> {
    public T o;
    public BigInteger r;
    public Power(T num, int pow) {
        BigInteger result = new BigInteger(1);
        for(int i = 0; i < pow; i++) {
            result *= num;
        }
        this.o = num;
        this.r = result;
    }
}
```

I looked around for a while for how to fix this, but I couldn't find an answer.

Can somebody help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you look at BigInteger javadoc?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`BigInteger` has operator methods for this. As `BigInteger` itself is immutable the value will need to be assigned to the result

For example the following

```
result *= num;
```

will become

```
result = result.multiply(num);
```

Answer (score 3):

[BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) has its own methods defined for arithmetic operations. Thus,

```
result *= num;
```

should be

```
result = result.multiply(num);
```

and similarly if you want to `add`, `divide`, or `subtract`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the multiply method inside the [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#multiply%28java.math.BigInteger%29) class.